# how to add values dynamically to array in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am using `angularjs`, I have one for loop and I get the loop values into one variable called `Name` .Now my need is that `variable` should store into scope array `selection` . How to achieve this.

## code:

```
$scope.selection = [];
     for(var i=0 ;i<$scope.Streams.length;i++)
                 {
var Name=$scope.Streams[i].Name;
  }
```

here i add the dynamic value of name into scope array.

I need output of my scope variable like this

[image]

Comment: your question is unclear..please be specified what you want.

Comment: now i update my code let me check @pengyy

Comment: `I need output of my scope variable like this` ... what does this mean?

Comment: i get my $scope.selection value like this mentioned in image

Comment: my loop is running  each time loop running time i get value in variable name now that name will store into scope selection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guess you want to add items of `$scope.Streams` to `$scope. selection`.
you can use `Array.push`.

```
$scope.selection = [];
// option1
for(var i=0 ;i<$scope.Streams.length - 1;i++) {
  $scope.selection.push($scope.Streams[i]); 
}
// option2 (with new instance)
$scope.selection = $scope.Streams.slice();
// option3
$scope.selection = $scope.Streams;
```

Comment: it's working fine but show only value i need the add column into scope.selection how to to this

Comment: @jose so you want the whole object be pushed not just the name of the Object?

Comment: @jose see my updated answer. I give you 3 options, pick the one you like.

Answer (score 1):

Try this single line of code with [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=example) method :

```
$scope.selection = $scope.Streams.map(item => { return {"Name":item.Name} });
```

**DEMO**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.Streams = [
     {
       "id":1,
       "Name":"stream1"
     },
     {
       "id":2,
       "Name":"stream2"     
     },
     {
       "id":3,
       "Name":"stream3"     
     }
    ];
    
    $scope.selection = $scope.Streams.map(item => { return {"Name":item.Name} });
    
console.log($scope.selection);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
</div>
```